# Rails: Refile gem (attachment_image_tag prints wrong URL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, refile

I'm using refile gem for file uploading and I'm uploading files directly to my amazon s3 public bucket. The files are being uploaded just fine to following URL:

`https://s3.amazonaws.com/{bucket-name}/store/6309035935359dca1ef549170e7facac9ab3553ad53946cea0bcb8335475`

I'm using amazon cloudfront to serve these assets from s3, so the cloudfront url, for the asset given above, is something like this:

`https://{distribution-name}.cloudfront.net/store/6309035935359dca1ef549170e7facac9ab3553ad53946cea0bcb8335475`

The both urls when accessed directly through browser works fine. To display this asset in my app view file I'm using refile gem following helper function:

`attachment_image_tag(@post, :profile_img, :fill, 350, 350)`

Now the issue is, this helper method prints a URL something like this:

`https://{distribution-name}.cloudfront.net/attachments/5845d0a97dc77a57b5b05742a1eb26d629d7cdaa/store/fill/350/350/6309035935359dca1ef549170e7facac9ab3553ad53946cea0bcb8335475/file`

As this URL is different from above cloudfront URL, it is not displaying the image. How do I force `attachment_image_tag` function to print the correct cloudfront URL?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved. The issue was pointed out by another guy on github: https://github.com/refile/refile/issues/500#issuecomment-239784247

> It sounds like you may have set up your Cloudfront distribution with
>   your S3 bucket as its origin? Refile, however, does not generate URLs
>   directly to files on S3 (see README section 3. Rack Application).
>   You'll therefore want to set your Cloudfront distribution's origin to
>   be the URL of your application. That way, files will be streamed from
>   your application on the first request, and cached by Cloudfront for
>   future requests.